# Relationship not eager loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

## Context

I have 3 migrations:

**Members** table:

```php
<?php   

class CreateMembersTable extends Migration
{    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
     
             $table->increments('id');
             $table->string('name')->unique();
             $table->timestamps();
        });
    }    
}
```

**Member Link Types** table:

```php
<?php

class CreateMemberLinkTypesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('member_link_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->string('name', 50)->primary()->unique();
            $table->string('category', 50)->index();
            $table->string('description', 50)->unique();
            $table->string('description_on_male', 50);
            $table->string('description_on_female', 50);
            $table->string('reverse_link', 50);
    });

    Artisan::call('db:seed', [
        '--class' => MemberLinkTypeSeeder::class
    ]);

    Schema::table('member_link_types', function ($table) {

        $table->foreign('reverse_link')->references('name')->on('member_link_types');
    });
}
```

And, **member links** table:

```php
<?php

class CreateMemberLinksTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('member_links', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('member_link_type', 50)->index();
            $table->integer('from_member_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('to_member_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('member_link_type')->references('name')->on('member_link_types');
            $table->foreign('from_member_id')->references('id')->on('members');
            $table->foreign('to_member_id')->references('id')->on('members');
        });
    }

}
```

After **seed member_link_types** table, it look like this:

```php
name   | category | description | description_on_male| description_on_female| reverse_link |
-------|----------|-------------|--------------------|----------------------|--------------|
child  | family   | Child       | son                | daughter             | parent |
parent | family   | Parent      | dad                | mon                  | child |
sibling| family   | Sibling     | brother            | sister               | sibling |
spouse | family   | Spouse      | husband            | wife                 | spouse |
```

So, I define the relationships at Member Link Class model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MemberLink extends Model
{        

    protected $with = [
        'from', 'to', 'type'
    ];

    public function from()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'from_member_id');
    }

    public function to()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'to_member_id');
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MemberLinkType', 'member_link_type', 'name');
    }    
    
}
```

## The problem

Given that I have the table 'member_links' like this:

```php
| id | member_link_type | from_member_id | to_member_id |
|----|------------------|----------------|--------------|
| 1  | parent           |      1         |       2      |
```

When I load the model

```php
$link = MemberLink::find(1)
```

I got this:

```php
App\MemberLink {#3012
     id: 1,
     member_link_type: "parent",
     from_member_id: 1,
     to_member_id: 2,
     from: App\Member {#3024
       id: 1,
       name: "Micaela Beltrão",       
     },
     to: App\Member {#3022
       id: 2,
       name: "Ian Fernandes",       
     },
     type: null,
   }
```

That is, the **to** and **from** properties were loaded successfully, but the **type** relationship did not (null).

However, if I try to get to the relationship directly from the object I get a different result:

```php
$link = MemberLink::find(1);
$link->belongsTo('App\MemberLinkType', 'member_link_type', 'name')->get()
```

Giving this:

```php
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3013
 all: [
   App\MemberLinkType {#3032
     name: "parent",
     category: "family",
     description: "Parent",
     description_on_male: "dad",
     description_on_female: "mom",
     reverse_link: "child",
   },
 ],
```

}

How get **type** relationship to be loaded?

I'm using Laravel 5.6.

## Update 1

Following Aarón Gutiérrez sugestion I add a Surrogate Key (integer column) as Key of member_link_types table, And after making the necessary changes:

```php
$link = MemberLink::find(1)
=> App\MemberLink {#3019
     id: 1,
     member_link_types_id: 1,
     from_member_id: 11,
     to_member_id: 12,
     created_at: "2018-08-14 14:28:46",
     updated_at: "2018-08-14 14:28:46",
     from: App\Member {#3031
       id: 11,
       name: "Simon Ferminiano",           
       created_at: "2018-08-14 14:24:49",
       updated_at: "2018-08-14 14:24:49",
     },
     to: App\Member {#3029
       id: 12,
       name: "Luciano Leon",
       
       created_at: "2018-08-14 14:24:52",
       updated_at: "2018-08-14 14:24:52",
     },
     type: App\MemberLinkType {#3030
       id: 1,
       name: "parent",
       category: "family",
       description: "Parent",
       description_on_male: "dad",
       description_on_female: "mom",
       reverse_link: 2,
     },
```

So, I suppose there is some limitation when I use the text field as the table's primary key, would it?

Comment: I wonder if `type` is reserved in some capacity. Can you try a different name for that relationship? Something like `public function linkType()`, and adjust your `protected $withs ...` to match.

Comment: I tried this but I did not succeed.

Comment: Hmm... At a glance, everything looks ok. If you run `dd(MemeberLink::find(1)->type)`, what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve.
It was necessary to set the `$incrementing` property to `false` in the `MemberLinkType` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MemberLinkType extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;    
    public $incrementing = false;    
    protected $primaryKey = 'name';    

}
```

After that, I got what I wanted:

```
$link = MemberLink::find(1)
=> App\MemberLink {#3071
     id: 1,
     member_link_type: "parent",
     from_member_id: 11,
     to_member_id: 12,
     created_at: "2018-08-14 15:03:22",
     updated_at: "2018-08-14 15:03:22",
     from: App\Member {#3065
       id: 11,
       name: "Gabriela Espinoza",           
     },
     to: App\Member {#3067
       id: 12,
       name: "Felipe Assunção",           
     },
     type: App\MemberLinkType {#3066
       name: "parent",
       category: "family",
       description: "Parent",
       description_on_male: "dad",
       description_on_female: "mom",
       reverse_link: "child",
     },
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose on your specific case for using a VARCHAR data type field as foreign key?

> The problem with VARCHAR being used for any KEY is that they can hold
>   WHITE SPACE. White space consists of ANY non-screen-readable
>   character, like spaces tabs, carriage returns etc. Using a VARCHAR as
>   a key can make your life difficult when you start to hunt down why
>   tables aren't returning records with extra spaces at the end of their
>   keys.

As stated here: [VARCHAR as foreign key/primary key in database good or bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103322/varchar-as-foreign-key-primary-key-in-database-good-or-bad)

So, that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\MemberLinkType')->withPivot('member_link_type');
```

from https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

EDIT sry did not see that it was not a pivot, have you tried.

```
$link->belongsTo('App\MemberLinkType', 'member_link_type', 'name')->with('type');
```

Comment: `belongsTo` is not a many-to-many relationship, so there's no pivot.

Comment: My mistake! This looked like a pivot table to me

| id | member_link_type | from_member_id | to_member_id |
| 1  | parent           |      1         |       2      |

Comment: It looks like one, but you can see that `MemberLink` is a Model for that table, which he is querying directly. Either way, I'm pretty sure using `->belongsTo()` with `->withPivot()` will fail (or at least not behave as expected)

Comment: Aha, the more you know ;)