# Database Design for Rental Listings

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm designing a **simple database for a rental listings website**,
sort of like classified ads but only for home/room rentals.  
This is what I've come up with thus far:

[image]

**Question 1**
For the "post" table, I actually wanted more information. For example, there would be a 'facilities' section where the users can select whether there's 'parking' available, do I need a separate table? Or just use 0 for no and 1 for yes?

**Question 2**
Here's what I did with the "category" table (sorry I don't know how to pretty print yet)
Category_ID 1 is Rent
Category_ID 2 is buildingType

For "categoryProperty" table
Category_ID 1 categoryPropertyID 1 House
Category_ID 1 categoryPropertyID 2 Room
Category_ID 2 categoryPropertyID 3 Apartment
Category_ID 2 categoryPropertyID 4 Condominium
Category_ID 2 categoryPropertyID 5 Detached

**Does the above make sense?**

**Question 3** 
Users can post whether they are logged in or not.
 Just that logged in users/members have the advantage of tracking their ads/adjusting the availability.
 
How do I record the ads that a member has posted? Like their history. 
Should I create a "postHistory" table and set the 'postHistory_ID' as FK to "member" table?

Thanks a lot in advance, I appreciate your help, especially just pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

make a separate table and make a One to One relation, that would be the simplest way:

POST -|-----|- EXTRAS

in EXTRAS you may have every extra field (parking=1/0, in_down_town=1/0,has_a_gost=1/0)

Question 2:
This does not make sense, you've two options:

in the Post table create a "type_of_operation", that can have two vales (building_type,rent). Or you can create different tables, but would make this more complicate (you should analyise if the same type can be in both states, etc).

Question 3:
I recommend you to make your users register. Even with a really simple form (email+password) .

Comment: 2. So you mean, the whole "category" table is unnecessary, and I should just include everything under the "post" table?

Comment: 3. Well, I was going to let them post ads first, and then register after, to encourage easy usage, but on second thought, yeah, just simple registration at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, just one category table. Don't mix the things up. I mean, "category" is different from the "type" of operation (or transaction, how do you wanna call it).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be on the right track -- with respect to your specific questions:

Question #1: Assuming there's more than one type of facility (parking; swimming pool; gym) then you have a many-to-many relationship and you want 2 new tables:  Facilities and PropertyFacilities.  Each Property (or I guess "post") could have multiple rows in the PropertyFacilities table.

Question #2: Not really clear on what you're getting at -- is it that each property type can either be rented whole or rented per room?

Question #3:  Good question, what you want to do is have an Active bit, or an ExpireDate, in your POST table -- then anything that becomes inactive or expired is automatically 'historical' data, no need to marshall it to a history table.  Although you'll have to archive eventually of course.

Comment: 2. I'm actually lumping everything up here. I was referring to this post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100008/can-this-mysql-db-be-improved-or-is-it-good-as-it-is . I have Categories like Rent, Buy, Sell, Building Type, Furnished. And then Category Properties for each like (Rent) House, Room (Buy) House, Apartment, (Building Type) Apartment, Villa, Semi-detached (Furnished) Yes, No, Partly.  Too complicated? Or should I just separate them into different tables?

Comment: 3. For History - I meant Archive, for example, User11923 had posted Post_ID 23, Post_ID 123, Post_ID 403 etc. Do I need an Archive table for that? But thanks for the tips on Active bit/ExpireDate though :D